# Status bar icons look wierd on some android devices

Tags: android, icons, statusbar

I'm currently developing an app for the android device which running in the background and pushing notifications sometimes. When notification is pushed an icon pops in the status bar. The problem is that in some devices it look too big and clipped but on others it's looks fine. For example when I'm testing the app on my personal device, Samsung Galaxy S3 android 4.2.2 and on a virtual device running android 2.2 it looks just fine. But when i tested the app on LG E400f - L Style android 2.3.6 it looks like this:
[image: How it looks like on LG E400f - L Style]

Anyone knows why this is happens?
Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply icons in the correct size for each platform. The documentation for that is [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html).