# How can show notification icon only on status bar

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to show a notification icon on the status bar with text not on notification drawer (like GPS icon). Currently I am using following code:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(CallReportAppApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext())
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_bell)
        .setTicker("Test");
notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop

Comment: but Display notification on drawer

Comment: in Navigation drawer? plz clarify your problem properly

Comment: NO Navigation  it's notification drawer . I want to show on Status bar only not any where.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977672/status-bar-icons-look-wierd-on-some-android-devices?rq=1) refer this url

Comment: do you followed this link https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html?